# Data type for holding the count of elements in a data structure

Tags: c, arrays, count, int, size-t

I have a dynamic array with the methods `push`, `pop` and direct acces to the buffer.
Intuitively I make the field containing the number of elements the array contains a `size_t`. Now I add methods like `insert`, `delete` and `indexOf`.

However, the first two expect an `int`as position to use negative indices for selecting elements from the back and `indexOf` either returns the found position or -1 to indicate failure, resulting in:

```
struct array {
    size_t num;
    char *buf;
}

void array_push(char c) {...}
char array_pop() {...}
void array_insert(int pos, char c) {...}
void array_delete(int pos) {...}
int array_indexOf(char c) {...}
```

With `push`/`pop` and a for-loop over `array.buf` with `array.num` I could still access up to `SIZE_MAX` elements. `insert` and `delete` can access only up to `INT_MAX` elements, though, and `indexOf` couldn't return positions over `INT_MAX`.

Would you consider this implementation correct or how would you change it?

**`size_t`**

*pro*: you can have up to `SIZE_MAX` elements

*contra*: you could access the portion above `INT_MAX` only in a limited way

**`int`**

*pro*: the interface would be coherent with the implementation

*contra*: you can't have more than `INT_MAX` elements in any way, also `int` for the size of an object is unintuitively as that's the purpose of `size_t`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that, in your case, it's more natural keep `size_t` and use `ptrdiff_t` instead of `int` for the function arguments and return values. You can find it in `stddef.h` and as the name suggests, it's intended to be used for array indexing and address arithmetic.

Be aware that although `ptrdiff_t` is the result of substracting two pointers, there's no guarantee that it doesn't overflow when doing so. So it can cause problems when you're dealing with very large objects, in which case it's probably better to use specified-width integer types, e.g., `int_fast64_t`.

Comment: I took `asprintf` as an example, which returns the length of a string (usually `size_t`, too) as an `int` or `-1` on error. In theory, if I used `ptrdiff_t` on x86 there wouldn't any difference as `PTRDIFF_MAX == INT_MAX`, on x86-16 `size_t` would be 2 bytes, but `ptrdiff_t` 4 bytes and thus unnecessarily big, on x86-64 I could additionally access the portion between `INT_MAX` and `PTRDIFF_MAX` with `indexOf`, etc., but the one between `PTRDIFF_MAX` and `SIZE_MAX` wouldn't be covered yet.

Comment: correction for x86-16: it would actually be the only one that worked due to the bigger size, as `ptrdiff_t` could index every possible element and also indicate an error or select from the back, although it would probably be slower

Comment: True, there's no guarantee that `ptrdiff_t` is wide enough to prevent overflow on pointer subtraction. In fact, some implementations make `ptrdiff_t` wider than `size_t` to avoid this. However, this is normally not an issue unless you're dealing with a very large data set.

Answer (score 1):

Don't restrict the implementation. Add methods with size_t arguments to the interface.

```
void array_insert_beg(size_t pos, char c) {...}
void array_insert_end(size_t pos, char c) {...}
...
bool array_find(char c, size_t *index) {...}
```